# .htaccess changing domain but not the rest of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I'm out of ideas to achieve the below:

I host 2 websites "A" and "B" on one server, as most of their elements are common.
"B.com" is web forwarding package - it forwards the user to "A/indexB.php".

All I want to achieve is when someone enter the "B" url it redirects to "A/indexB.php" document, but the "B" domain should remain.
I can't use "B" as Masked Redirection Type, as people browsing the "B" website instead of seing links like "B/link" they would see only "B".

Is there any .htaccess solution?

Answer (score 0):

If "B" redirects to "A/indexB.php" then where should redirect "B/link"?

I'm not an expert, but it seems that you're trying to adapt global redirect (based on domain -- i.e. redirect everything from B.com) to a specific targed (script A/index.php). I'm not pretty sure, if this is possible.

I would consider using server / hosting configuration for defining a permanent redirect between "B" and "A". Or even would think about configuring "B" domain as Addon Domain (which can point to a particular path in your account, not only root). But this again returns me to the question in first line and I'm a bit confused, if it is possible, what you want to achive?